# Error in auto-generated files created while building RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, auto-generate

I am a new Android Studio user, also new to Java. I am building a new project, and followed this tutorial to add a RecyclerView to my project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk. The app appears to build correctly, but now immediately crashes on opening on my device. It was working fine before that. The error messages lead me to the auto-generated files that were created during this process.

I have tried following the error messages to the files, and cannot figure out how to fix them if that is indeed the problem. In searching for a solution with the search terms 'recyclerview', 'android studio' 'cannot resolve symbol' etc., I found several recommendations to upgrade to Android Studio 3.3. I was already on 3.4.0, but I tried upgrading to 3.4.1. No change. I tried changing the dependencies in my `build.gradle` file, which didn't seem to change anything either. Most of the other answers I found had to do with `cannot resolve symbol 'RecyclerView'` which is not a problem I am having at present. I have also tried **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...> Invalidate Caches and Restart** several times, as I saw it recommended in several places.

In following the files, I found several places where `import androidx.recyclerview.R;` results in the `cannot resolve symbol 'R'` error and several places where `lst.elementData` works fine in one part of the file, but not in another, resulting in `cannot resolve symbol 'elementData'`.
My current build.gradle dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.0.0'
}
```

The last function I can be sure is getting called is:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");

        holder.itemName.setText(mItemName.get(position));
        holder.itemDue.setText(mItemDue.get(position));

        holder.listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + mItemName.get(position));

                // Insert navigation here
            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see from the error log below. 
The only code I added from the last time my project worked is from the tutorial I followed, with minor tweaks to the names of some of the variables, and replacing the image on each list item with a second TextView.

Error messages in the Log are:

```
2019-05-16 00:46:04.247 12824-12824/? D/RecyclerViewAdapter: onBindViewHolder: called
2019-05-16 00:46:04.248 12824-12824/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-05-15 23:44:28.830 4480-4480/com.example.divideanddestress E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.divideanddestress, PID: 4480
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.example.divideanddestress.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
        at com.example.divideanddestress.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:16)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:954)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2711)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2426)
2019-05-15 23:44:28.831 4480-4480/com.example.divideanddestress E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1569)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7296)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:930)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:705)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:640)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:916)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: By the time `mItemName.get(0)` is executed, `mItemName` is empty, hence the exception.

Comment: JulioE.RodríguezCabañas The method that sets the value for `mItemName` is getting called before the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare mItemName=new ArrayList() before use the arrarylist and check itemCount value.

Comment: That is already done following the tutorial that I linked to. The getItemCount method is called, and returns that the size of mItemName is 1. Even if it were 0, my understanding is that it should show an empty RecyclerView, not crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both the people who answered/commented. After looking at what you were focusing on, I figured out that the mItemDue ArrayList wasn't being populated. After fixing that, the app seems to be working fine.